# How to match element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<!-- MainMenu -->
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="About/xxxxx">About</a></li>    
    <li><a href="Services/xxxxx">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio/xxxxx">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /MainMenu -->


<!-- MainMenu -->
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="xxxxx/subpage1.html">About Main</a></li>    
    <li><a href="xxxxx/subpage2.html">About Main</a></li> 
    <li><a href="xxxxx/subpage3.html">About Main</a></li> 
</ul>
<!-- /MainMenu -->
```

And following jQuery, which already cut URL into needed to matching bits.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    urlParts = "www.website.com/About/subpage1.html".split("/")
    var MainMenu = urlParts[1]+"/"; // mainmenu e.g About/XXXX
    var SubMenu = urlParts[2];      //submenu e.g XXXX/subpage1.html


    // Find matched to var = MainMenu within main-menu > li > a
    // Find matched to var = SubMenu within sub-menu > li > a


});
```

What I want to do:

- Find matched to **var = MainMenu** within **main-menu > li > a** and addClass('active') to matched 'a'
- Find matched to **var = SubMenu** within **sub-menu > li > a** and addClass('active') to matched 'a'

**So how can run through those menus looking for matches to those var?**

**http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/gWDm8/124/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[name^="..."]` and `[name$="..."]` selectors to match attributes that start and end with specific strings:

```
$('.main-menu > li > a[href^="'+MainMenu+'"], .sub-menu > li > a[href$="'+SubMenu+'"]')
.addClass('active');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gWDm8/127/

Comment: What is the difference between: `href^=` and `href$=` ?

Comment: @Pete: `^=` matches the start of the value, i.e. `[href^="About/"]` matches the element with `href="About/xxxxxx"`. `$=` matches the end of the value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute selector.

```
item = $('.main-menu > li > a[href="' + MainMenu + '"]');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I think OP only wants it to match where the `MainMenu` matches the *start* of the `<a>`'s href under `ul.main-menu`, and the `SubMenu` matches the *end* of the `<a>`'s href under `ul.sub-menu`. Like [@Guffa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610861/how-to-match-element/6610934#6610934).

Comment: Nearly there. Your solutions is perfect but there is a error. Should be '$('.main-menu > li > a[href^="'+MainMenu+'"]'

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.main-menu li a').each(function() {
     if( MainMenu == $(this).attr() ) $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but probably inaccurate solution is the usage of the `:contains` pseudo selector:

```
$('ul.main-menu').find('li:has(a:contains(' + MainMenu  + '))').addClass('active');
```

That will add the class `active` to the parent `li node` which contains an `anchor`, which contains the string. More accurate is an exact matching:

```
$('ul.main-menu, ul.sub-menu').find('a').each(function(_, anchor) {
    var $anchor = $(anchor),
        parts = $anchor.attr('href').split(/\//);

    if( parts[0] === MainMenu || parts[1].indexOf(SubMenu) > -1 ) {
        $anchor.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MKH3Y/

Answer (score 0):

You can assign ids or classes to each element and go one by one, or you can use `.each`.

For instance:

```
$("ul > li").each(function(){
... your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(".main-menu > li > a[href^='" + MainMenu + "']");
        $(".sub-menu > li > a[href$='" + SubMenu + "']");
```