# Link (or a linkable DIV?) with background image + highlighting

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, background, highlight

I see this in Facebook (also Google), but can't figure out how to do it. I took a screenshot of the Facebook nav bar below,

[image]

Several questions,

1. It doesn't seem like this is highlighting the link only - i.e., not doing this through modifying the `<a>` tag alone - `a:hover`, etc. The entire element (probably a `<li>`) is being highlighted - does this mean the entire `<li>` element itself is a link? Or maybe they're just putting a lot of spaces (e.g., `&nbsp;`) in front of the link text? Doesn't seem like they're doing that either.... How is this done?
2. How do you do a highlight AND a background image? Seems like the background color overrides the background image...?
3. How do you get the link to know where you are? Is this done through JavsScript, where when I click on a link, I modify its CSS to stay highlighted, and remove all the permanent highlights from the other links in the navbar? I could probably figure out how to do this, just wondering if this is the only way to do it.

Thanks a million for answering my newbie questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify **different CSS for an `<a href="#">LINK</a>` element when on hover** - it will have an effect as you have described. **[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/avNvn/)**

E.G.

```
a { background: #fff img1.png no-reapet left top; font-weight: normal}
a:hover { background: #000 img2.png no-reapet left top; font-weight: bold}
```

**In this example we have changed *background color, background image and font weight* when the element is on :hover.**

**Q1:** If you have an `a href` inside the `li` and you add `display:block` to the `a href` - `a href` will get as big as the parrent `li`. Which than can look as `li` is an `a href`

Also, if you add `display:block` to the `a href` it can serve as a condtainer for `spans img em's etc..` elements -  creating one big link which can looks like a div. **e.g [here](http://www.webiq.co/service.html) you have a link `a href` which contains desc + img.**

**Q2:**  When you specify both - background image and background color for the same element - background image WILL always be on TOP.

Please note that:

`a { background-color: #fff; background-image: url(img1.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top left}`

is the same as:

`a { background: #fff url(img1.png) no-repeat top left}`

**Q3:** You can add a class to the clicked element through JS to stay highlighet - but unless you save this value in the DB it will be lost when you reload the page.

Second option is that you can use javascript / jQuery to match URL of the links with current URL and mark matched element (**[see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610861/how-to-match-element)** - jQuery).

Comment: @reedvoid - CSS and jQuery will work in this case the same in every browser - this is very basic CSS and basic jQuery.

Comment: @reedvoid - we can add `:hover` effect to pretty much to anything (p, div, ul, li etc..), but IE8 and lower will have a problem with on `:hover` effect for elements other than `<a href="#"></a>`

Comment: I just tried it in JSFiddle and it doesn't seem to work - when you hover over the background color overrides the background image: http://jsfiddle.net/reedvoid/avNvn/51/

Comment: Wow... it just worked and I have no idea why, the code is exactly the same. Very strange.

Comment: @reedvoid - this is because your img on `:hover` is failing to load. Make sure the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1) here is an example on how you can achieve what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/UKna2/1/

CSS

```
li:hover {
background-color: lightblue;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;  
}
```

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>    
</ol>
```

2) All they probably do is set an image icon to the list item instead of the standard numbering or bullet.  Read up on this : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp